# Convert LastBootUpTime from WMI to a more friendly format

Tags: wmi, ironpython

I have an IronPython script that gathers some info from WMI. One of the items I'm trying to gather is `LastBootUpTime` from `Win32_OperatingSystem`. I'm able to get the info using:

```py
import clr

clr.AddReference('System.Management.Automation')

from System.Management.Automation import (
    PSMethod, RunspaceInvoke
)
RUNSPACE = RunspaceInvoke()

def wmi(query):
    return [dict([(prop.Name, prop.Value) for prop in psobj.Properties]) for psobj in RUNSPACE.Invoke(query)]

def to_ascii(s):
    # ignore non-ascii chars
    return s.encode('ascii','ignore')

operating_system = wmi('Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -Namespace "root\CIMV2"')[0]
last_boot        = to_ascii(operating_system.get('LastBootUpTime'))

print last_boot
```

The result is as follows

```
20161117135516.486400-300
```

Is there a way in IronPython to convert this "timestamp" to a more friendly format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the methods found in the [`ManagementDateTimeConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementdatetimeconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) class to convert to a .net object.  That field in particular is a `datetime` so you'll want to use [`ToDateTime()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementdatetimeconverter.todatetime(v=vs.110).aspx).  You'll just need to add a reference to the `System.Management` assembly.

```py
clr.AddReference('System.Management')
from System.Management import ManagementDateTimeConverter
print ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(last_boot)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you.